# Why this wrong?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

Value of record.Time is "11/01/2012 11:38:01:296"

```
string[] capturetime = record.Time.Split(':');
string captime = capturetime[0] + ":" + 
                 capturetime[1] + ":" + 
                 capturetime[2] + "." + 
                 capturetime[3];
DateTime rightTime = Convert.ToDateTime(captime);
```

After the second line run the value of captime is "11/01/2012 11:38:01.296"
Error appear at the last line : "Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: lengthmscorlib"

I dont understand why. Because it run fine before :( Anyone  can explain this ? tks so much

Solved, tks everybody so much :)

Code :

```
 string[] capturetime = newRecord.Time.Split(':');
                string captime = capturetime[0] + ":" + capturetime[1] + ":" + capturetime [2] + "." + capturetime[3];
                DateTime righttime;

                if(time[3].Length == 2)
                {
                    righttime = DateTime.ParseExact(captime, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.ff",
                                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                } else
                {
                    righttime = DateTime.ParseExact(captime, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff",
                                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
```

So any idea for optimizing those code ????

Update :

Is it me or my Visual Studio is Crazy??? The new code above got exception like the old code and when i changed back to the old code. It work fine like the old day ..wth is this :(

Comment: can you provide the string[] capturetime value., by breakpointing it?

Comment: capturetime value is split the capture time into 4 part
[0] = 11/01/2012 11", [1] = "38" , [2] = "01", [3] = "296"

Comment: it is working fine on my machine. Why do you split it and then paste it together again? what's the point? TELL US WHAT YOU WANT FROM THIS CODE, MAYBE WE CAN HELP BETTER THIS WAY.

Comment: well.. then checkwhether capturetime[0], capturetime[1].. capturetime[3] are in int  or Timespan values.

Comment: Just so it's said, `Regex.Replace(":(?=\d+$)", ".", record.Time)` (or something similar, i forget the exact syntax) would state the intent of the code more clearly.

Comment: @mahditahsildari: The point of the split/paste is to replace the last colon with a period.

Comment: because the milisecond style in the database I have to save in is . not : so I have to convert : to .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best way to solve this is by using the CultureInfo/DateTimeFormat strings.

However, if that's not applicable for you for some strange reason, here is a crude way of doing this.

```
        string val = @"11/01/2012 11:38:01:296";
        string[] parts = val.Split(' ');
        var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(parts[0], "dd/MM/yyyy", new DateTimeFormatInfo());
        double[] times = parts[1].Trim().Split(':').Select(s => double.Parse(s)).ToArray();
        dt = dt.AddHours(times[0]);
        dt = dt.AddMinutes(times[1]);
        dt = dt.AddSeconds(times[2]);
        dt = dt.AddMilliseconds(times[3]);

        // OR -- dt.AddMilliseconds(times[0] * 60 * 60 * 1000 + times[1] * 60 * 1000 + times[2] * 1000 + times[3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
string dateString =  "11/01/2012 11:38:01:296";    
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString , "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss:fff",
                                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: this code worked for value "11/01/2012 11:38:01:296" but got exception like above with this value "11/01/2012 11:37:59:62"

Comment: Hi bui watch the format again. "fff" is 3 digits, meanwhile you just enter 2 digits

Comment: What is the culture used to create the Time string above? If you know that you can use DateTime.Parse(timeStr, CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat)

Comment: that time string is value I got from a MySQL Database

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely, the time you have given, doesn't have the last COLON. As per normal standards, It would be a dot.
Check RecordTime value properly.

"11/01/2012 11:38:01:296" is wrong
"11/01/2012 11:38:01.296" is correct

Hence making the indices of captureTime wrong. It would be, 0, 1 and 2. 
3 would be out of bounds.

Comment: that's it. So i have to replace that : by . to add to database

Comment: What is the datatype of Record btw?

Answer (score 0):

just use DateTime.ParseExact(val, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", new DateTimeFormatInfo()) without doing all the string splitting.